# ¿Cómo restar el valor viejo y sumar el valor nuevo a un campo acumulador?

Tags: javascript, primefaces

el problema que quiero resolver es que tengo un formulario en el cual tengo un campo en el cual inserto un valor numérico y en otro campo se va acumulando el valor de mi primer campo. Estos son mis campos el primero esta en un encabezado que es un reporte de gastos  y el segundo en un formulario para items de gastos igual anexo el botón en el que llamo a mi función Acumular().

Esto funciona bien al momento que agrego un item de gasto se va acumulando en el campo del encabezado, el problema es cuando modifico un item de gasto, necesito a mi campo acumulador restarle el valor viejo sumarle el valor nuevo, pero no se como recuperar el valor viejo con JS. Espero alguien me pueda ayudar.

```
 <div class="form-group input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">* Total de gastos: </span>
                            <h:inputText class="form-control"  a:id="acumulado" value="#{reportExpensesBean.reporte.totalExpense}"  a:type="number" a:disabled="true"/>
                        </div>


 <p:outputLabel value="*Total de gasto"/>
                     <h:inputText class="form-control" value="#{reportExpensesBean.gasto.totalExpense}" a:type="number" a:min="0" a:id="valor" /> 



  <p:commandButton value="Aceptar" oncomplete="PF('dlNuevoGas').hide();" 
                                                 actionListener="#{reportExpensesBean.nuevoGastReport()}" 
                                             update=":formMostrarGastosReport"
                                             onclick="Acumular()">


                                </p:commandButton>
```

igual agrego el script

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
         var variableAcumuladora = 0;
function Acumular() {


         var valor = parseInt(document.getElementById("valor").value);
            valor = isNaN(valor) ? 0 : valor;

            variableAcumuladora += valor;

            valor=document.contact_form.valor.value;
            variableAcumuladora=document.contact_form.acumulado.value=variableAcumuladora;

            }</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola Araceli pues mira en vez de usar una variable que inicializa en 0, usa el campo en donde almacenarás,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Acumular() {    
            var valor = parseInt(document.getElementById("valor").value);
            valor = isNaN(valor) ? 0 : valor;

            var varAcumulado = parseInt(document.getElementById("acumulado").value);
            varAcumulado = isNaN(varAcumulado) ? 0 : varAcumulado;

            document.getElementById("acumulado").value = varAcumulado +valor;

            }</script>
```

Ahora si lo que necesitas es restar, no entiendo por que tu función se llama Acumular().
Te sugiero mejor definir un coportamiento, es decir si necesito restar el valor ingresado poner un boton de restar, es lo que se me ocurre, igual y si das más contexto te puedo apoyar.
**Saludos**

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, !! creo que no le di el contexto adecuado a mi problema, mira la función Acumular funciona bien ya que cada que agrego un item de gasto el valor que le doy al campo Total de gasto, se acumula perfecto en el campo Total de Gastos. El problema es que necesito crear otra función que se llame restar en la que  cuando modifico el valor del campo Total de gasto, necesito que ese cambio también se vea reflejado en  el campo Total de Gastos, es decir que el nuevo valor también se acumule pero que el valor viejo se reste.